# Are there tilemaps without images?

Tags: tilemap, tiled

I would like to use Tiled or a different editor to create a simple world (top-down).
But I don't want to use any images. I just need colors to distinguish the different types of terrain.

What would be a good approach?

I thought about using Tiled and creating a Map with a tilesize of 1px. As Tiles I could use 1px by 1px big images containing just one color. But this feels odd and not nice.

Answer (score 1):

Tiled creates data unrelated to the image you use, so you can do what you want with the data created.

In the [TMX format](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/stable/reference/tmx-map-format/), tiles' positions are stored separately from the image associated with them. It's just an ID. You can retrieve this ID in your program independently from the image since they are not directly related.

So it doesn't change anything very relevant in your output file whether you use a tileset with a single color or a fancier tileset. It's just comfort for you when you create your map. All you need after is to identify the ID corresponding to each tile.